# How to have custom API URLs in Web API 4 for .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

In .NET 4.5, we can add the `Route` decorator to define the route to an API call like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("libraries/{libraryid}/books/{bookid}/checkout")]
    public IHttpActionResult CheckoutBook(long libraryId, long bookId,
                                    [FromUri] long utcTimestamp)
    {
    }
```

However, in WebAPI for .NET 4, we don't have access to that Route decorator.  How do we define custom routes for specific API calls?

Comment: For the record, it's an Attribute, not a Decorator.

Comment: Did you do any research? There are thousands of results for "WebAPI Routes"

Comment: I think you are looking for the `[ActionName]` attribute, combined with the RouteConfig file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute routing was a Nuget package before being integrated into the framework:

[AttributeRouting.WebApi Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi)

Comment: Is there a documentation of this api somewhere? I added the package in my project but it seems namespaces are not the same as it is in .net4.5

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis if you are using .net 4.5 and web api 2, attribute routing is part of the framework. The package I mentioned is for older versions. You can read more about this here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2